# How to reflect font awesome icons in the react project?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I have added the CDN link to the index.html of my React project.

You can check that in this [repo](https://github.com/sarajune/react-learning/blob/main/public/index.html)

Added this line on line 16:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

And added the i tags to my Components.
Line 14,15 lines in this [file](https://github.com/sarajune/react-learning/blob/main/src/components/Header.js)

```
<Nav className="mr-auto">
    <Nav.Link href="/cart"><i className="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>Cart</Nav.Link>
    <Nav.Link href="/login"><i className="fas fa-user"></i>Login</Nav.Link>
  </Nav>
```

But, the page is not showing the icons.

[image: preview of icons page]

Please suggest, how to fix this?

The repo link: [github](https://github.com/sarajune/react-learning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get started you’ll need to install the following packages into your project using a package manager like `npm` and `yarn`.
https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

---

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

---

And Simply use Like this

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const element = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
```

Comment: Does adding the cdn link won't work?

Comment: Thank you, I updated the icon references in the same way

Comment: @SaraJune I did not find anything on this subject(CDN Links) in the official doc's..  You're welcome, glad to help you :-) !